# Python parsing tree-like data

Tags: python, parsing

I have a glyph information from a font that looks like this:

```
(CHARACTER C T
   (CHARWD R 0.6944475)
   (CHARHT R 0.686111)
   (COMMENT
      (KRN C y R -0.027779)
      (KRN C e R -0.083334)
      (KRN C o R -0.083334)
      (KRN C r R -0.083334)
      (KRN C a R -0.083334)
      (KRN C A R -0.083334)
      (KRN C u R -0.083334)
      )
   )
```

Is there a straightforward way to parse this in python? I've used BeautifulSoup before, but it requires nested `<tag> </tag>` like information. It wouldn't be to hard to convert this to XML and back again - but it seems like it would be reinventing the wheel. How would I get this information into a data object that I can manipulate and spit back out again?

Comment: Parsing such a structure isn't hard in principle (in fact, it looks like it should be pretty easy if you know what the fields mean and what they may contain). But if you want all the cool features of the element tree API, your best bet is indeed converting it to XML. Or, less cool but still ok, create a DOM from it. If you don't need no fancy API, you can also just parse it into your own hand-rolled data structures.

Comment: @delnan has it with just parse it into your own data structure.  Unless you are looking to try and interact with another library or similar that requires the data in a certain form, parsing it into your own data structure is probably the most straightforward.  If you really want to use a standard style, try json.

Comment: @brc: Well, if there's a lot of programmatic manipulation of such data planned, and converting it to XML is easy, I'd favour that personally. `lxml` makes working with XML a breeze, which may outweigh the conversion overhead (overhead for the programmers, not in performance).

Comment: A quick hack would be to munge it a little with regex and then read it into a tuple using `ast.literal_eval`. You could then work on the tuple (or rather tuple of tuples) or convert it into xml and then work on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [pyparsing](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing).  Your example looks very much like an [s-expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-expression), and they have an s-expression parser in their [examples section](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/Examples): http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/sexpParser.py

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Comment: @PaulMcG, thanks for pointing this out... I've updated the link in my answer

Answer (score 2):

This will convert your data into a python data structure. Not sure if it's what you're looking for?

```
s = """(CHARACTER C T
       (CHARWD R 0.6944475)
       (CHARHT R 0.686111)
           (COMMENT
           (KRN C y R -0.027779)
           (KRN C e R -0.083334)
           (KRN C o R -0.083334)
           (KRN C r R -0.083334)
           (KRN C a R -0.083334)
           (KRN C A R -0.083334)
           (KRN C u R -0.083334)
           )
        )"""

s = re.sub("\)", "\),", s)
t = re.sub('([(,\s])(\w+)', '\\1"\\2",', s)
eval(t[:-1].replace('\\', ''))
```